# cURL request intermittently fails on specific call, Postman works just fine

Tags: php, curl

I've created an integration with a logistics company for a ecommerce platform and in order to get certain delivery data, there's a POST request to the API. This request is fulfilled by PHP code and uses cURL to make the request. This works perfectly 99.9% of the time, what's strange is that certain requests are consistently failing. These requests are structured similarly to the others and simply result in a timeout.

If I submit the same request through Postman, I get the desired response. The logistics company is suggesting the error lies in my implementation and I'm open to that being the case. Can anyone assist?

```
$log = new Log('LOG.log');
if($quote['pargo'] == 1){
    //make request to URL - need to get city and postal code from $json
    $url = "[http://requestEndPoint]".$requestString;
    $log->write('API Request= ' . $url);
    $ch = curl_init ($url);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type:application/json",
        "Authorization: [apiKey]"
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $log->write('API Response= ' . json_encode($response));

    if($response){
      $obj = $response;
    }
    else{
      $obj = curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    $counter++;
}
```

On the specific calls that fail, the response received from the server is:

```
400 Bad Request
```

The nature of the request is to get info on a given address in the provided format (city, country). An example of a working `$requestString` is below:

```
Sandton, Johannesburg, South Africa
```

Below is one that fails consistently with cURL but works in Postman

```
Hermanus Heights, Hermanus, South Africa
```

Comment: Please provide more details about failing requests. Failing how? Is there an HTTP reponse error code? Or does it fail before the request can be made?

Comment: Thanks @JackTheRandom, I've updated the question with the response and example requests. Note the API documentation does not encode the strings in the URLs

Comment: Have you tried to [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your `$requestString`? Or even use [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)? It is unclear how your `$requestString` is exactly structured. It is not defined in the code you have given.

Comment: I'm open to doing so @KIKOSoftware the `$requestString` is structured exactly as the examples above. The only reason they aren't excoded is due to the API documentation. I'll give it a try and test since the error is consistent enough across the cities using cURL

Comment: All I am worried about is that you may be using a malformed URL.

Comment: @Daniel does the platform you are integrating with have a sandbox with demo credentials by any chance? :-) But yes, I agree with KIKO Software, most likely the URL is malformed somehow or Postman does something different (e.g., uses POST instead of GET, etc.).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware your suggestion was correct. What bugs me is that a previous iteration had been using `urlencode()` and for some reason it was commented out and the raw string used instead.

Comment: @JackTheRandom I wish they did! It still bugs me that some URLs work perfectly fine and some consistently don't but at least the issue is resolved!

Comment: Nice that it was so easy to solve.